Issues with implementing a custom ScrollPhysics class which clamps after a certain amount of underscroll
In Flutter, I am implementing a SingleChildScrollView widget which I am trying to tweak a bit to fit my needs:

After underscrolling a certain amount of pixels, clamp the scroll view and execute a callback. The bigger picture is that this callback will animate out the current page as the user is scrolling.

To start I have created a custom ScrollPhysics class which inherits AlwaysScrollableScrollView() as a parent. I have then overrided the applyBoundaryConditions(position, value) method to allow a certain amount of underscroll before clamping. This part works great, and allows the user to overscroll a little bit before stopping. When the user lets go the scroll view then settles back to 0.0.
Note that the callback is called regardless of underscrolling (for complicated reasons not important), but logic higher up will use the provided metrics to then close the page.
class CustomScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  /// how much can we underscroll by
  final double underscrollAllowance;
  
  /// callback which closes page based on scroll metrics
  final Function(ScrollMetrics position, double value, bool isUnderscrolling)?
      onScroll;

  CustomScrollPhysics(
      {ScrollPhysics? parent, // parent in this case is AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
      this.onScroll,
      required this.underscrollAllowance})
      : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  CustomScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return CustomScrollPhysics(
      parent: buildParent(ancestor),
      underscrollAllowance: underscrollAllowance,
      onScroll: onScroll,
    );
  }

  
  @override
  double applyBoundaryConditions(ScrollMetrics position, double value) {
    bool isUnderscrolling = value < position.minScrollExtent;
    onScroll?.call(position, value, isUnderscrolling); // make callback

    // if we are underscrolling over allowance then clamp.
    if (value < (position.minScrollExtent - underscrollAllowance)) {
      return value - (position.minScrollExtent - underscrollAllowance);
    }

    // allow unlimied scroll when inbounds and underscroll.
    return 0.0;
  }
}

The Issue
The problem I am having is when the user flings the scroll view. In the case that this happens, the page gets stuck at the limit defined by underscrollAllowance but doesn't bounce back as I would expect. I pressume fling physics are handled a bit different but can't for the life of me figure out how or where.
I think the ideal solution is that if the user flings the page, the default AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics behaviour takes effect.
Any help / ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)
Update 1
I have managed to make a bit of progress by overriding the createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity) method.
@override
Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {

    // When the user lets go of the scrollable, create a simulation to bounce back to the boundary.
    if ((position.pixels < position.minScrollExtent)) {
      return ScrollSpringSimulation(
        spring,
        position.pixels,
        position.minScrollExtent,
        0.0,
      );
    }

    return super.createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity);
  }

Now, if the user flings the page and underscrolls before releasing their finger, the scrollable will bounce back nicely. This however still leaves a small corner case that persists the previous issue if the user were to fling, but the page underscrolls after the release of their finger.
